# angular is not defined

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have a problem in my file route.js when I'm running with Node.js it shows me **"angular is not defined "**

**route.js**

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']);
       app.config(function($routeProvider){
         $routeProvider
            .when('/', {templateUrl: 'views/login.html'})
            .when('/login', {templateUrl: 'views/home.html'})
            .otherwise({redirectTo : '/'});
 });
```

**error :**

[image]

Comment: Just don't forget to include angular in your html page. Just saying ... Post index.html code

Comment: @ Bixi I have already done that in all the pages and the same problem 
Info: route.js and page.html are Separate

Answer (score 0):

Have you "imported" the angular.js scripts?

```
script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js')
script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular-resource.min.js')
```

This [page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-nodejs-polling-app/) gives some info on how to do a MEAN stack (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node). Perhaps it has some usefull information for you.

Comment: why the jade-oriented answer ??